# Shouldn't the reputation be hidden in the questions?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I've encountered a situation when there was two answers on the question, one long, with a lot of '2+2==4' statements, but absolutely nonsense, and one short, telling the source of the problem with a couple of solutions. Long one was coming from the user with 20k, and the short one was answered by the user with 1k.

Finally the long answer was accepted and upvoted while the other was ignored (but it's still there and can help someone).

So the idea is: should the reputation be less visible, for the sake of clear view of the problem concerned and to get a higher quality voting?

(I won't advertise the question as this can be offensive to the author of first answer)

Comment: Devil's Advocate: Who would you rather perform your surgery, a 10-year surgeon or a nurse?

Comment: This works the other way - you see the result of surgery before you decide, while the nurse is possibly more talented than this 10-year surgeon.

Comment: True. Yes it's correct that showing the reputation of the author does influence voting decisions - humans are more likely to go with a person who has more experience even if it's only on the face. You just need to learn to look past that. If Jon Skeet posts a bad post, downvote it.

Comment: Personally I only use up vote when the answer helped and worked, and don't use down at all(every info is useful, but correct/working should come first), but here the question is laying in the mass psychology field, you can't teach everyone how to vote, it should work by nature.

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov "Every info is useful": you clearly have not seen some of the truly DV worthy crap we get.

Comment: I took a look at your reputation and am not convinced that you understood the long answer.

Comment: @HansPassant The question is theoretical possibility of increasing the voting and I'm not convinced you've looked at the proper question... though if the curiosity is burning inside feel free to contact me personally, I'll explain the details(Ruby). :)

Comment: If you would like to hide such info for yourself, someone created a script to hide that information here: http://stackapps.com/questions/3105/hide-all-pointless-user-data-gravatar-badges-and-reputation

Comment: @BSMP thanks, will give it a try

Answer (score 6):

Your concern boils down to,

> Showing the reputation of a post author influences voting.

And to that I say: yeah, so?

Reputation is a "loose measure of the community's **trust**" in that user.

Let's say you're sick. You go to the pharmacist and they tell you to take medicine X, but the person behind you in line tells you to take medicine Y instead. Yes, you can judge the content of their responses, but you need to weigh *who* they are as well. One is a licenced medical worker and one a stranger.

So what do you want to do, take away the only bit of credibility that user can show when they post an answer? Why not hide the entire avatar box and make the responses *truly* anonymous?

Yes, the reputation can influence voting. But you can vote *for whatever reason you want*. We can't regulate how people vote - that's a given. If you want a "rich gets richer" you can do that. If you upvote for an even number rep and downvote for odd, go for it. The system suggests (though the tooltips) that you vote based on if the content is helpful/useful, which has nothing to do with the author at all.

I feel that users want to see if the answerer is credible, and that information should outweigh the cons of voting patterns based off of it.

Comment: For the particular case of SO I believe we should avoid opinion-based answers, thus making decisions based on reputation is wrong. In the programming(derived from mathematics) you can definitely say what's true and what is not.

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov That is totally not true. There are many, many ways to solve every programming problem, some better than others (and what's better can be context dependent, or even an opinion if its a design/style issue).

Comment: And I don't consider high reputation as a measure of richness, I use SO for self-education while helping people.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET then why there are so few sorting algorithms? Because there is theoretical optimum and you can't do any better than that(very unlikely). Computers are predefined 0 and 1 processing machines...

Comment: You "can" vote for whatever reason you want in the sense that neither the software nor administrators will prevent you (short of serial voting), but you _should_ vote on your honest judgement of the merits of the post's content, not for spurious reasons like the parity of the author's reputation. Doing otherwise subverts the intended signal of post scores (and reputation).

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov Again, thats not true! Even in that simple example, different sorts are better in different situations. For example, in a nearly sorted list, a bubble sort is *far* better than a quick sort. Computers may be binary, but programming (and programming design/algorithms) most certainly isn't.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yet you won't need to know where the algorithm came from, you can just measure the performance and tell which is better for your problem, thus the reputation is useless. And if you take first solution not looking at the others based on the author experience you run into situation I'm talking about.

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov Sure, but the analogy still holds. If Jon Skeet tells me a bubble sort is better in my situation, I'm far more likely to listen to him then user282111 who says quick sort is better because I, and the community, trust him more (which reputation is a rough measure of). Showing that he is a (potentially) more reliable source has value. Of course, trying every solution is a great idea (one a googler may not have time for), but I don't think showing the reputation really affects that. We may just have to agree to disagree here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET doing so you will ignore user12345 which will advise you to use [insertion sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/insertion-sort) for your nearly sorted data :)

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov That is an unfortunate possibility, yes (which is why you should read multiple answers). Mitigating that to a certain extent is that high-rep users will commonly check back on their posts and may see such an answer and may comment on it noting that it is better or even delete their own post.